If you think about it, why are all roots of unity on the unit circle?
Let's say we discovered $\mathbb{C}$ freshly for ourselves and we haven't developed any tools yet.
We don't know that $\mathbb{C}$ has the norm $|a + bi| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ and we especially don't know that
$e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i \sin (x)$.
What could possibly hint at the fact that if $(a + bi)^n = 1$ for some $n$, that then $a^2 + b^2 = 1$?
I assume mathematicians even before Argand and Gauss developed the complex plane must have realised this after computing some examples, so how did they explain that to themselves?

Well, $(a-bi)^n=\overline{(a+bi)^n}=1$, hence: $(a^2+b^2)^n=(a+bi)^n\cdot (a-bi)^n=1$. But then $a^2+b^2=1$.

To the extent you're interested in the actual development by Argand and Gauss, the History of Science and Math SE may be a better place for this question.

What you need to know is this: The magnitude of the product of two complex numbers is the product of their magnitudes.

How do you know that the norm of a complex number was not discovered at, or even before, the moment of discovery of complex numbers themselves?

@GBA Why not an official answer?

If you construct the complex numbers algebraically then conjugation is a natural operation to consider since $i$ and $-i$ are algebraically indistinguishable. From there it's not hard to see that $(a+bi)(a-bi)=a^2+b^2$ which is a a non-negative real number. Now for a positive number $k$ we have that if $k^n=1$ then $k=1$ which forces $a^2+b^2=1$. Since this conic defines the unit circle you can see why Gauss may have wanted to interpret the complex numbers as points in the plane.

Added as official answer:
$$(a-bi)^n=\overline{(a+bi)^n}=1\Rightarrow (a^2+b^2)^n=(a+bi)^n\cdot (a-bi)^n=1\Rightarrow a^2+b^2=1$$
